# Slideout from right to left on div with a variable width.

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i'm currently struggling to get a div with a variable width to slideout from right to left.

the problem is getting the button to animate along with the sliding div, see example below.

http://camoconnell.com/things/slideoutleft/

note -  width is dynamic, not static.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/p5kcp/). It's not quite as simple as you'd think right off the bat.

Comment: hey bryan thanks for help, i tryed your example in jsfiddle & could get it working (i'm probably missing something). had a look in the console, it output'Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' (anonymous function)' .

Comment: got it,  i needed to place within jQuery(document).ready, works a charm! thanks again

Answer (score 0):

With the way you have your html structured you will have to do a .animate() on the dynamic div's width and set the width property to negative of whatever length you are sliding your counter div to

```
.animate({width: -50})
```

Make this call right before or after your slider invocation.

Another suggestion is to put the button and the counter elements in a wrapper element (this would require a restructure of your html) and just slide out that wrapper element.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to apply the animation to the wrapper div. So in your slideRightShow, you can have:

```
$('#caption').show();
$('#caption-wrap').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be another solution:

HTML:

```
<div class="test" id="hithere">Hi there, <a href="#" id="hide">Hide me</a></div>
<a href="#" id="show">Show me</a>
```

CSS:

```
.test {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS

```
var variableWidth;

$(window).load(function() {

// gets complete element width (including margins), moves it out of the screen and sets visibility to its default
    variableWidth = $('#hithere').outerWidth(true);
    $('#hithere').css("left", variableWidth * -1);
    $('#hithere').css("visibility", "visible");
});

$("#show").click(function() {
    $('#hithere').animate({left: 0}, 400);
    });

$("#hide").click(function() {
        $('#hithere').animate({left: variableWidth * -1}, 400);
        });
```