# Sliding a Div Left to Right and Back

Tags: jquery, html, animation, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get my sidebar to slide left to right and back by any way possible. I also need it to have a handle so that people can click it and it will slide out and then completely disappear when they close it. This is the HTML that I have so far and my CSS if that makes a difference. I'm just getting started as a designer so I'm not really sure how to handle this. I've looked a lot online but can't find a plugin so if anyone could suggest a plugin or help me with the code that would be great.

```
<div class="s-b-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="s-b-border"><a href="#"><i class="icon-calendar"></i> Syncro</a></li>
    <li class="s-b-border"><a href="#"><i class="icon-file"></i> BoM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-hdd"></i> Override</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


.s-b-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(182, 182, 182, 0.71);
  line-height: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.s-b-menu ul li {
  padding: 4px;
}

.s-b-border {
  border-bottom: dotted 1px;
}

.s-b-menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
}

.s-b-menu ul li a:hover {
  background: rgba(16, 0, 225, 0.74);
}

.s-b-menu ul li#active {
  background: #0ff;
}
```

Comment: have you tried studying a bit about jquery? Try `animate` in the jquery library

Comment: As he said, jQuery is going to be the way to go. You could attempt to do something with CSS3 Transiitions but it won't be as compatible.

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085423/slideout-from-right-to-left-on-div-with-a-variable-width/8085756#8085756). Check out the jsFiddle in my answer to see an example of animating a `div` in and out.

Comment: Here is an example using jquery animate function [via jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PC6Er/)

Checkout jquery's animate properties. It may be a bit slower than its alternatives in some cases but I find it more multi browser friendly on many occasions

Comment: @Chanckjh studying the `.animate()` function most likely won't help him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/MgcDU/5482/

fixed CSS so the Menu text doesn't jump around.

HTML:

```
<div class="s-b-menu-hidden">
    Menu <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
</div>
<div class="s-b-menu">
  <ul>
      <li id="menu-close">Menu <i class="icon-arrow-left"></i></li>
    <li class="s-b-border"><a href="#"><i class="icon-calendar"></i> Syncro</a></li>
    <li class="s-b-border"><a href="#"><i class="icon-file"></i> BoM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-hdd"></i> Override</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".s-b-menu-hidden, #menu-close").click(function(){
    $(".s-b-menu-hidden").toggle();
    $(".s-b-menu").toggle();
});
```

CSS:

```
.s-b-menu-hidden {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(182, 182, 182, 0.71);
    position: absolute;
    padding: 12px;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.s-b-menu-hidden:hover {
    background-color: rgba(200, 184, 184, 0.71);
}

.s-b-menu {
    display: none;
}

.s-b-menu:hover {
    display: block;
}

.s-b-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(182, 182, 182, 0.71);
  line-height: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.s-b-menu ul li {
  padding: 4px;
}

.s-b-border {
  border-bottom: dotted 1px;
}
.s-b-menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
}

.s-b-menu ul li a:hover {
  background: rgba(16, 0, 225, 0.74);
}

.s-b-menu ul li#active {
  background: #0ff;
}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need but it needs to be on click because it could be used on tablets. Is that an easy fix?

Comment: absolutely, i'll update the fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/3fwMG/1/ Note i gave them somewhere to click in the opened menu because it will do the close when they click a link too.

Comment: How would you make it so the clickable tab is still on the side? That way it's obvious how you close it. That's just the designer in me talking. :P

Comment: I would use an arrow on the menu to do that, make an arrow pointing to the right when closed and an arrow pointing to the left when open.  Also to make it not auto close on link click you would need to edit my jquery selector.  Such as bootstraps icons

Comment: How so? Sorry if I seem ignorant. I'm just trying to understand how so I can do it on my own next time.

Answer (score 0):

[**here is a jsfiddle describing the basics**](http://jsfiddle.net/uFLM5/) of one approach i have taken utilizing the javascript library "[**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/)"

the other answers may be "toggling" the display of your element but i dont see the animation you are looking for so i put together this - with this approach we are actually animating the expansion and contraction of the sidebar element using this particular set of jquery:

```
$('#toggle').click(function(){
    $('.s-b-menu ul').animate({width: 'toggle'});
});
```

it is an onclick event for the element with id #toggle - which calls jquery "animate" call with parameter width toggle.  thus on click will animate the sidebar open and closed horizontally.  enjoy and if you have any questions leave a comment

*EDIT: reply to comment*

in your question you said you wanted a "handle" people can click to op
en your sidebar. define your handle element and replace my "#toggle" with its selector

Comment: if you take a look at my code - ive added a "div" that has the id "toggle" you may or may not want to use that exact approach - in your question you said you wanted a "handle" people can click to open your sidebar.  define your handle element and replace my "#toggle" with its selector

Comment: like I could replace it with an image url?